# Kafka messaging with different types of Data and Comparing perfomance

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am sending messages from Kafka producer to Consumer in python.

In Producer i am senting data like this:

```
producer.send(topicName,str.encode( message_data))
```

And in Consumer getting the data with:

```
for msg in consumer:
   # print("Message from Producer on Topic - "+msg.topic+":"+ msg.value.decode())
```

Here the data is in bytes.
Similarly ,I need to sent data in different datatypes and compare the perfomance.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka always stores data in bytes. You can use any data type you want, for example, you could use `pickle` or `json` (although that would still be a string) instead of just encoding a string variable

Some Kafka Python libraries expose a serializer function rather than you explicitly handling serializing between clients

Comment: If I am senting the data in JSON or in bytes.How can I understand its perfomance.How much it took to sent the message etc

Comment: You may use Python's `timeit` module, but performance testing Python code isn't specific to Kafka, so I'm sure you can find resources elsewhere for that